# Custom control in swift looping infinitely in xcode playground

Tags: uiview, swift, xcode6

I'm using XCode's playground feature to develop a custom control. However, I'm having issues using sub-routines (methods) to break up the drawRect implementation.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class CustomView : UIView
{
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var color = UIColor(red: 0.571, green: 0.857, blue: 1, alpha: 1);
        var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect);
        color.setFill();
        ovalPath.fill();
        // if I uncomment this, the code runs in an infinite loop...
        // drawCircle(rect);
    }

    func drawCircle(rect: CGRect) {
        var color = UIColor(red: 0.571, green: 0.857, blue: 1, alpha: 1);
        var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect);
        color.setFill();
        ovalPath.fill();
    }
}

var cv = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400));
```

If I uncomment the line noted above that calls the drawCircle function - the code hangs in an infinite loop.

Why is this?

Comment: Could not reproduce this infinite loop in a project. I think this is a bug in Playground.